# Recitation of Chandipath

Tags: devi-bhagavata-purana, vedic-chanting, chandipath

In Bengal, we have the tradition put forward by Acharyas that Chandipath is not to be chanted at night. Unfortunately I have no sources or references to quote. Could anyone please tell me whether its valid, or is it just one of those unexplained regional traditions put forward by interpolation or modification? Thank you.

Comment: Chandipath does have rules around parayana. It is to be done after upadesam.

Comment: I understand that. But what I was speaking about is the time of day. Even after upadesam I have heard many Acharyas and pandits say that it is not to be chanted at nighttime. Is there any reason for this? Or is it just some modification.

Comment: sAttvika sAdhana is usually carried out during daytime.

Comment: I see, so could you tell me what happens, or is there any adverse effect, if we chant it at night?

Comment: The guru who gives upadesam shall also give rules around parayana.